# Forced re-authorize using LinkedIn with Oath

Tags: oauth, passwords, authorization, linkedin-api

If it possible to force a re-authorization (I.E asking for username and password) from the LinkedIn oauth api?

Usecase:
To protect sensitive data, in case someone forgets to log out, some actions on our site can only be taken after you re-verify yourself with your password (even when logged in). We allow login using LinkedIn, in which case the user does not have a separate password on our site. In this case we would like to force a re-authorization (username/password) from the LinkedIn api so that user can still confirm his identity.

The important issue here is that it cannot just accept because the user is already logged in on LinkedIn and has accepted to app, this would not provide any level of security for someone who has forgotten to log out, it has to explicity ask for authorization by password again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to force re-asking of the OAuth username/password once the user has logged in other than to log them out of LinkedIn first.

You can see this in action by opening your LinkedIn JSAPI-enabled site and having the user 'Sign in with LinkedIn'. Once you have completed the initial OAuth sign-in/authorization, open a tab in the same browser and go to linkedin.com - you will also have been logged into the site.

In your case, if the user simply walks away from the computer leaving the browser open, they will still be logged into both of your site AND linkedin.com. Closing the browser, or logging out via the API or the linkedin.com site will solve this.

One strategy might be that any access to 'sensitive' data generates a logout, which will clear the cookies but not the app authorization, and then to instantiate the auth dialog:

```
IN.User.logout();
IN.UI.Authorize().place();
```

Details [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/inauth-inevent-and-inui). I've tested this and it seems to work well.

Comment: Thanks, but how would this work if the user has saved his login info in the browser? If it is a normal login call the browser will probably be allowed to pre-fill the fields, thus invalidating any security.

So it would solve the "I forgot to log out at the library" problem as you don't save things there. But not the "I forgot to lock my computer at work" problem, as there people will have their passwords saved.

The more I search the more I become sure that LinkedIn simply doesn't provide this option. So I'll have to do something else instead.

Comment: I'm confused... your questions asks how to force the user to re-enter their password, and when shown how to do that, you say that it doesn't handle the case where the user has the password stored in the local browser... how would one trigger a clearing of locally stored passwords from a web page?

Comment: You don't unless you have control of the form (which we of course do not have as it is on LinkedIn). But some APIs (such as Facebook) implement a re-auth call that does not allow browsers to prefill the form, specifically made for cases like this.

So the question is if LinkedIn has anything similar.

Comment: Well that's not what your question above asks explicitly (you might want to link to the Facebook functionality you are referring to), so might want to edit it accordingly. And no, there is nothing in the LinkedIn API that will force the browsers to disable remembering form data.

Comment: As the whole point (by the final paragraph) was to force an actual reauth, I thought that was kind of obvious, but I'll be more explicit next time.

Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a logout call when a user wishes to logout from your site,
simply make them call an iframe request to https://www.linkedin.com/secure/login?session_full_logout=&trk=hb_signout and return a successful signout message when that happens. Sounds dodgy (xss attack) but this is probably the only non-intrusive way of logging the user out.

Comment: This doesnt seem to work anymore. It says you are logged out. But you are actually still logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small jQuery plugin that I wrote to help accomplish this.

First, add a `data-hidden-iframe` attribute to your standard "Sign Out" in your application.

```
<a href="/signout" data-hidden-iframe="https://www.linkedin.com/secure/login?session_full_logout=&amp;trk=hb_signout">Sign out</a>
```

Note that the `data-hidden-iframe` attribute value points at the LinkedIn logout URL that Ernest recommended.

Next, add this jQuery plugin to load a hidden iframe with the LinkedIn logout URL. It will wait until the iframe is fully loaded before propagating back to default click behavior.

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("[data-hidden-iframe]").loadhiddenIframeBeforeClick()

$.fn.loadhiddenIframeBeforeClick = ->
  this.on "click.iframe", ->
    return if $(this).data("already-iframed")
    event.preventDefault()
    event.stopPropagation()
    href = $(this).data("hidden-iframe")
    $(this).data("already-iframed", true)
    $("<iframe style='display:none;'>").attr("src", href).appendTo("body").load =>
      $(this).trigger("click")
```

For those that cannot read CoffeeScript, here's the equivalent JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  return $("[data-hidden-iframe]").loadhiddenIframeBeforeClick();
});

$.fn.loadhiddenIframeBeforeClick = function() {
  return this.on("click.iframe", function() {
    var href,
      _this = this;
    if ($(this).data("already-iframed")) return;
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    href = $(this).data("hidden-iframe");
    $(this).data("already-iframed", true);
    return $("<iframe style='display:none;'>").attr("src", href).appendTo("body").load(function() {
      return $(_this).trigger("click");
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question in which I am answering.. But it can help someone to get out of this problem

There is a solution I have recently implemented just create a fake `webview` call with the actual logout url for linkedin that is

https://www.linkedin.com/secure/login?session_full_logout=&trk=hb_signout

Just call the above url with a fake webview, incase of iOS it could be

```
UIWebView *webView=[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
NSURLRequest *req=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.linkedin.com/secure/login?session_full_logout=&trk=hb_signout"]];
webView.delegate=self;
[webView loadRequest:req];
```

Hope it helps someone..

Answer (score -3):

If you want to force the user to re-login with their Linked In credentials, then just take them through the authorization process again. However, it will have to be the entire authorization process with Linked In requesting the user to authorize your application and you storing a new OAuth token.

Comment: Well yes, but the question was how to do it.

Comment: You need to "forget" that you have the OAuth token for this user and start the OAuth process in your application again.

Comment: Hm, that still wouldn't work as authorizing an application does not required you to sign with a password, so if the user is already logged in it will be as simple as clicking ok.